# Create Different number of columns each row in a table with PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

I would like to make a table with different numbers of cols with PHP and with data from mysql.

I got very stuck because i don't know how to do that with For and foreach. I am so lost.

I have in my MYSQL database 40 datas entries. I want to create a php script with the result of all of each data I take from my mysql. The first while-loop mysqlfetch array appear in 1 colomn, the 2nd one in 2 columns, the third one 2 colomns, the Four one 1 colomn etc.. In continue with the same structure all over again. Instead to make it appears one colomns by 1 colomns. It's 1 colomn, 2 colomns, 2 colomns, 1 colomns

[Example result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mYRw.jpg)

thank you so much !

Comment: Relational databases do not have different numbers of attributes (columns) your description is incoherent. Does "columns" refer to some sort of  tabular output? I have no idea what you are trying to illustrate with the linked image.

Comment: @symcbean I was trying to do exaclty what rolland showed me to do. sorry if my explanation was not clear. It was soooooo HARD FOR ME to explain. I don't have ANY ANY ANY CLUE how rolland did the script but the result was exactly what I was  expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style>.item{ border: 1px solid; padding:15px; display: inline-block; }
</style>
<?php

$db_data = array('Vetements', 'Pres 1', 'Couleurs', 'Questions', 'Conjon', 
'Prepos', 'Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'Dollar', 'Ammet', 'Ellet', 'Orion', 
'Vetements', 'Pres 1', 'Couleurs', 'Questions', 'Conjon', 'Vetements', 'Pres 
1', 'Couleurs');

$i = 6; 
foreach($db_data as $k => $item){

//show data here
echo "<div class='item'>$item</div>";

if($i % 5 == 0){
        echo "<br>" ;
        $i = 5;
} else{

    if($i % 2 == 0){
        echo "<br>" ;
    }

}

$i++;   

}
```

Comment: Everybody is so nice here to help ! wow . I am going to try and see !! Thank you so much

Comment: You are the best ! I love it ! Wow. I am very thankful for your help. I really do appreciate. Thank you so much !!!!

Comment: I don't understand anything about how you did it but i need to learn every line you put on it. thank you !!!

Comment: Great! The logic is: For each 5 items, put a line break (<br> or your preferred method to separate the items). Inside it, break again for each 2 items.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a little lost in your head ^^.
If you want get SQL data with PHP you can test that.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title FROM table";
$conn = config_db();

$result = $conn->query($sql);
foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
   var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but i want to give the same result that What I attached in the message  - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mYRw.jpg    -   1 column, 2 columns, 1 column, 2 column